# Найти разность между смежными элементами массива

Tags: c#, linq

Имеется массив, например:

```
var x = new [] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
```

Нужно найти разность между смежными элементами, соответственно:

```
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} -> {1,1,1,1,1,1,1}
```

Как это можно реализовать штатными средствами?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, так: `x.Zip(x.Skip(1), (first, second) => second - first)`.

Comment: Благодарю, то что нужно!

Answer (score 1):

Еще вариант с использованием [Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb548744(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var result = x.Skip(1).Aggregate(new { prev = x[0], result = Enumerable.Empty<int>() },
    (acc, cur) => new
    {
        prev = cur,
        result = acc.result.Concat(new[] { cur - acc.prev })
    },
    a => a.result.ToArray()
    );
```